# 2 chars to signed short

Tags: c++, char, integer, signed

I have two char values `char_1` and `char_2`. Now I want to combine them to an 16 Bit signed integer value where `char_1` contains the sign in the MSB.

> |SGN|Bit 6|Bit 5|Bit 4|Bit 3|Bit 2|Bit 1|Bit 0|Bit 7|Bit 6|Bit 5|Bit
>   4|Bit 3|Bit 2|Bit 1|Bit 0|

| Sign Char 1 | Rest of Char 1 | Char 2 |

My try was:

```
signed short s = (((int)char_1) << 8) & (int)char_2;
```

Now I get 0 for `s`...

Comment: Note that your implicit assumptions on integer sizes are non-portable. Consider using the fixed-width types `std::int8_t` and `std::int16_t` from `<cstdint>`.

Comment: It is portable to assume that `signed char` will be able to hold a signed 8 bit quantity, and it is portable to assume that short will hold a signed 16 bit quantity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a bitwise `or` not `and`

```
(((int)char_1) << 8) | (int)char_2;
```

Since you're also dealing with bits, you should probably use unsigned types too (unsigned char, unsigned int, unsigned short.)

Comment: I'm a fool. Thank you!

Comment: The cast of `char_2` needs to be to `(unsigned int)`.  If char is signed on your platform, and char_1, char_2 == 1,0xff, then you will end up with (1<<8) | (-1) ... which probably isn't what you wanted!

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution might be achieved by Unions.

```
typedef union { short int s; char c[2];} Data;

int main (){
        Data d;
        d.c[0]=char_2;
        d.c[1]=char_1;
}
```

**Note:** This may not be portable enough for you as the order of the indexes depends on architecture endianness. My example works well on Little endian archs (ie Intel 0x86) but big endian archs would print `char_2 char_1`.